# 08-12 22:58:04.181: W/System.err(6430): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20140812163222" (at offset 14)

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

ErrorLog
08-12 22:58:04.181: W/System.err(6430): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20140812163222" (at offset 14)

```
String testDate = "20140812163222";
        SimpleDateFormat setDateFormet = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        try {
            Date parseDate = setDateFormet.parse(testDate);
            String resultdate = setDateFormet.format(parseDate);

            Log.d("TAG","Result => " + resultdate);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

To convert the time the error occurs. 
Help...
 thank you

Comment: Using the same formatter for both parsing and formatting isn't likely what you want, and the input is not in the format you specified to the parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use an extra Dateformat to parse the input:

```
    String testDate = "20140812163222";
    SimpleDateFormat inDateFormet = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    SimpleDateFormat setDateFormet = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    ....
    Date parseDate = inDateFormet.parse(testDate);
    String resultdate = setDateFormet.format(parseDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your testDate string does not match the format given to SimpleDateFormat's constructor. Try:

```
SimpleDateFormat setDateFormet = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
```